# Счетаем значения по кол-ву пропусков в ряде

Tags: python

Как вычислить значения `a=0,b=0,c=0` из списка h? Значения формируем путем подсчета пропусков между цифрами.

```
h = [nan,10,nan,nan,20,20,nan,nan,nan,5,nan,4,nan]
```

Сначала между 10 и 20 - это будет значение `а = 3`. Затем 20 и 5 - это будет значение `b=5` (20,20 - подряд не считается, берем только первое), затем 5 и 4 - это значение `c=2`.

a,b,c это три значения которые будут получены, но например для `c` может не хватить значения из списка, тогда оно все еще будет 0. Также может появится дополнительная буква d к примеру, поэтому делаю на вырост так сказать.
*Как можно правильно сделать такое, максимально компактно в пару строчек?*

Comment: Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу ([править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1283847/edit))

Comment: Не цифрами, а числами.

Comment: @АндрейТи, ну так выложите код сюда, авось кто поможет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Идти по списку, считать элементы пока они равны стартовому числу или nan. Если элемент не равен стартовому или nan, то начинать новый счётчик. И таким образом продолжать до конца списка.

На выходе будет список с искомыми диапазонами. Первый (до первого числа) и последний (после последнего числа) отбрасывается, т.к. они вам не нужны.

```
nan = None
h = [nan,10,nan,nan,20,20,nan,nan,nan,5,nan,4,nan]

last_num = None
res = [1]
for elem in h:
    if elem in (nan, last_num): 
        res[-1] += 1
    else:
        res.append(1)
        last_num = elem

res = res[1:-1]
print(res)
```

Результат:

```
[3, 5, 2]
```